# Comparison of pointer to integer errors in standard C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm changing my code from variable to pointers and I'm having a bit of trouble. Where it used to work with (largely abbreviated):

```
int best = 0;
int max = 10;
if (max > best) {
    best = max;
}
```

I'm trying to use pointers so that I can use pass-by reference to abstract it into a function.

```
int *best;
*best = 0;
int max = 10;
if (max > *best) {
    *best = max;
}
```

I get segmentation faults at the `(max > *best)` line. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how it got even that far because of:

```
int *best;
*best = 0;
```

You are simply grabbing 4 bytes which have some (unknown to you) previous value, interpreting that as a memory location and writing all zeroes on it.

Longer explanation: `int *best` gives you use of the name `best` to refer to a memory location. Trouble is, you have not specified *which* memory location you want. Since a pointer is nothing more than a number of bytes in memory, and those bytes hold *some* value (even unused memory holds *some* value), in effect your new pointer is pointing to an unknown memory location. When you dereference it, *bad things happen*.

Try it this way:

```
int someInt = 0;
int* best = &someInt;
*best = 0;
```

Now you know what memory you are overwriting with zeroes: the piece that was properly reserved for the variable `someInt`.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, your `best` isn't being initialized, thus it will point to an unknown address. You may want to point it to an existing `int`. For example:

```
int best = 0;
int *best_ptr = &best; // Now best_ptr points to best
printf("value is %d\n", *best_ptr);
```

Or maybe allocate memory for it instead:

```
int *best_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)); // Allocate
if (best_ptr != NULL) {
    *best_ptr = 0;
    printf("value is %d\n", *best_ptr);
    free(best_ptr); // Deallocate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're assigning an address to the pointer, not a value. Change it to this:

int* pbest;

int best;

pbest = &best;

*pbest = 0;

int max = 10;

if (max > *best) {

```
*best = max;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that you can't assign a integer to a pointer

instead , you should assign a position to a pointer like

```
int score;
int *best = &score;
```

and then you can assign an integer to socre

```
score = 0;
```

Comment: an address is an integer. Assigning an integer to a pointer forces the pointer to point to that address in memory. It probably isn't the right thing to do, but is it valid C.